# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when I click a gaming mouse extra button

Tags: 18.04, mouse, freeze

I am experiencing freezing issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and the Logitech g300s model, I am not sure if this issue affects other mouse models.

In order to test this it is simple:

Open terminal, click the mouse extra buttons, Ubuntu freezes for a few seconds where mouse pointer still works and if you type something with your keyboard it will only display what you typed after the freeze stops, which means the application keeps receiving the input during the freeze.

I have searched the forums all around and the only thing I found was some users relating some autosuspend related problems, but this is not the same issue here.

I also found a thread relating the issue for Ubuntu 17.04 without a solution so far.

Note that mouse was working just fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It's a problem with gnome-shell. Checkout https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1777708 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1858#note_818548